# jQuery running slow; want to find out what is still running

Tags: jquery

My page slows down after a while of use. I am thinking that is because some of my jQuery functions never stop running once they are executed. Is there a way to check what is still running so that I can find out where my bug lies?

Thanks!

Comment: Try Chrome DevTools (with Google Chrome or Chromium browsers) https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: This video was just released by Addy Osmani that talks a little bit about the chrome dev tools for performance profiling. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KKwmdTByxLk

Comment: If you tell us the url, we can maybe find out whats hogging it.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. @AndersLindén, I am still developing the site locally, so I don't have a link

Comment: So I went over the video posted above, and I noticed that my code actually has no memory leak, and the memory is fully released after the event runs (great!). BUT the site still starts to lag after a while. What is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) for debugging. Start firebug open your page and see in the console tab what is going on. Also I recommend to check your ram memory usage. If you have some kind of jQuery functions which are cycling over and over again and cacheing some date in your memory this can make your page to going slow down.